# ReduceByKey on Iterable value of tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to count the appearances of specific Items at a specific date.

My input's structure is `Date\tItem1:AppearencesOfItem1,...,ItemN:AppearencesOfItemN`

**Example**

```
20/10/2000\tItem1:1,Item2:5
20/10/2000\tItem1:2
21/10/2000\tItem1:5
```

In order to do that, I create the following PairRdd structure:

```
[(20/10/2000, (Item1, 1))
(20/10/2000, (Item2, 5))
(20/10/2000, (Item1, 5))
(21/10/2000, (Item1, 5))]
```

and then `groupByKey` on the date which leads to:

```
[(20/10/2000, Iterable[(Item1, 1), (Item2, 5), (Item1, 5))
 (21/10/2000, Iterable[(Item1, 5)]
```

What I want to do after this step is reduce the value of these pairs and sum the appearances of the items that share the same key so that the outcome will become like:

```
[(20/10/2000, Iterable[(Item1, 6), (Item2, 5))
 (21/10/2000, Iterable[(Item1, 5)]
```

However I haven't figured a way to reduce on the value of these pairRdds. Is my approach wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be achieved by two steps:

1. Sum by first two columns
2. GroupBy (or reduceBy for performance) by first column

   ```
   val data = List( 
     ("20/10/2000", "Item1", 1),
     ("20/10/2000", "Item2", 5),
     ("20/10/2000", "Item1", 5),
     ("21/10/2000", "Item1", 5)
   )
   val originalRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(data)

   val sumRDD = originalRDD.map(v => ((v._1, v._2), v._3)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
   sumRDD.map(v => ((v._1._1), (v._1._2, v._2))).groupByKey().foreach(println)
   ```

Output:

```
(21/10/2000,CompactBuffer((Item1,5)))
(20/10/2000,CompactBuffer((Item1,6), (Item2,5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, it may be not he most elegant way but it seems to match your requirements:

```
rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(x => x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2).sum))
```

First map your values to group by itemId, then over that grouped list, map the values again to keep only the second element (the integer) so you can sum it up straightly

**Output:**

```
scala> rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(x => x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2).sum)).foreach(println)
(21/10/2000,Map(Item1 -> 5))
(20/10/2000,Map(Item2 -> 5, Item1 -> 6))
```

**Edit**
I was creating a map inside your RDD, if you want it as List or something just perform a `toList`

```
rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(x => x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2).sum).toList)
```